# C# Binding Datatable to DetailsView

Tags: c#, data-binding, detailsview

I'm trying to bind a datatable to a detailsview, however not all records that are in the datatable are being displayed in the detailsview.

For example, my datatable will have 2 distinct rows.  When bound to the detailsview, it allows me to page between 2 pages, however the details on each page are identical and do not show the individual results that are in the datatable.

I am binding as such:

```
            DetailsView1.DataSource = dt;
            DetailsView1.DataBind();
```

I'm not sure if this matters, but when the details view is first bound it is done so using DataSourceID to the SQLDataSource.

EDIT: I am handling the pageindexchanging event.

Thanks.3

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the [Paging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms227442.aspx) event.

Comment: Hi, I am handling the pageindexchanging event as such:  DetailsView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;  However this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

may need to call DataBind() in your paging event after page is changed:

```
DetailsView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex; 
DetailsView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I have also tried that aswell! When I DataBind it, the DetailsView shows no records at all when the paging option is selected.

Comment: I have a search function which allows me to search a persons name and then populate the detailsview, but once this happens when I try to page between records it throws an error for example; Searching Jones, then multiple records are populated with the name Jones. When I try to page the records it throws an error.